OpenTelemetry & Blazor Hybrid: Spans/Activities are not logging to Console/File
I have a Blazor Hybrid application, where I'm attempting to use OpenTelemetry + NLog to log client information to a file on disk. I'm trying to get the ActivitySource entries to log to my log file, and console, so I can see the timespan and other information. I need some help getting everything configured correctly (and reducing the what information is being logged... (see info below).
Below is my setup:
Basic Info
Using .NET8, with a Blazor Hybrid project. There is no appsettings.json entries for open telemetry. NLog logging to the file is working as desired. OT is logging to the console... but it's not useful information to me (currently) and the app is very slow when enabled:
LogRecord.Timestamp:               2024-05-13T14:21:06.2594275Z
LogRecord.CategoryName:            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer
LogRecord.Severity:                Debug
LogRecord.SeverityText:            Debug
LogRecord.Body:                    Rendering component {ComponentId} of type {ComponentType}
LogRecord.Attributes (Key:Value):
    ComponentId: 82
    ComponentType: MudBlazor.MudOverlay
    OriginalFormat (a.k.a Body): Rendering component {ComponentId} of type {ComponentType}
LogRecord.EventId:                 3
LogRecord.EventName:               RenderingComponent

Resource associated with LogRecord:
service.name: <APP NAME>
service.instance.id: 32a40416-826e-444a-a138-485d89f3ed32
telemetry.sdk.name: opentelemetry
telemetry.sdk.language: dotnet
telemetry.sdk.version: 1.8.1

LogRecord.Timestamp:               2024-05-13T14:21:06.2778115Z
LogRecord.CategoryName:            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer
LogRecord.Severity:                Debug
LogRecord.SeverityText:            Debug
LogRecord.Body:                    Rendering component {ComponentId} of type {ComponentType}
LogRecord.Attributes (Key:Value):
    ComponentId: 83
    ComponentType: MudBlazor.MudElement
    OriginalFormat (a.k.a Body): Rendering component {ComponentId} of type {ComponentType}
LogRecord.EventId:                 3
LogRecord.EventName:               RenderingComponent

EDIT
(Added IDisposable and usage for clarification)
The ActivitySource is being created in a helper class that also implements IDisposable and is doing all the necessary disposal, etc. If the class is needed, I will edit to show, but the activity is created and then used like so:
        public Telemetry([CallerMemberName] string methodName = "")
        {
            _MethodName = methodName;
            _Activity = TelemetryConstants.ActivitySource.StartActivity(_MethodName);
            AddTag("operation.datetimeoffset.utcnow.begin", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString(_DateFormat));
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            AddTag("operation.datetimeoffset.utcnow.end", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString(_DateFormat));
            _Activity?.Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

Usage:
            using (var telemetry = new Telemetry())
            using (_Logger.BeginScope($"{nameof(DeleteTblEventChoice)}:{eventChoiceId}"))
            {
                _Logger.LogDebug($"Delete {nameof(tblEventChoices)} with ID: [{eventChoiceId}]");
                return _TblEventChoicesRepository.DeleteTblEventChoice(eventChoiceId);
            }

MauiProgram.cs
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();

...

builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .ConfigureResource(resource => 
        resource.AddService(serviceName: TelemetryConstants.ServiceName, serviceVersion: TelemetryConstants.ServiceVersion)
    )
    .WithTracing(tracing =>
    {
        tracing
            .AddSource(TelemetryConstants.ServiceName)
            .AddConsoleExporter(options =>
            {
                options.Targets = OpenTelemetry.Exporter.ConsoleExporterOutputTargets.Debug;
            });
    })
    .WithMetrics(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddConsoleExporter(options =>
        {
            options.Targets = OpenTelemetry.Exporter.ConsoleExporterOutputTargets.Debug;
        });
    })
    ;

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
builder.Logging.AddNLog();

builder.Logging.AddOpenTelemetry(options =>
{
    options
        .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService(TelemetryConstants.ServiceName))
        .AddConsoleExporter(options =>
        {
            options.Targets = OpenTelemetry.Exporter.ConsoleExporterOutputTargets.Debug;
        });
});

CSProj Package References
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.21" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.21" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui" Version="8.0.21" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="MudBlazor" Version="6.19.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="5.3.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="5.3.11" />
        <PackageReference Include="NLog.Targets.MauiLog" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry" Version="1.8.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Api" Version="1.8.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console" Version="1.8.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting" Version="1.8.1" />
    </ItemGroup>

EDIT 2
I've resorted to just implementing it the activity source like so:
using (ActivitySource activitySource = new(TelemetryConstants.ServiceName, TelemetryConstants.ServiceVersion))
using (var telemetry = activitySource.StartActivity(nameof(AsyncGetAll)))
using (_Logger.BeginScope($"{nameof(AsyncGetAll)}"))
{
    telemetry.AddTag("TEST TAGGGGSSS", "my address");

    return await _Repository.AsyncGetAll();
}

Here the telemetry object is NULL. When looking at ActivitySource, it states that NULL is returned when there are no event listeners. So that is the main problem I'm attempting to solve now.

I don't see where you're stopping the activity, it won't flush until that happens, then your code needs to be running for a period of time before it will flush to the console (it's not synchronous).

@MartinDotNet I've added the IDisposable implementation and usage. The activity is getting disposed (I think) properly.

To debug, try just manually disposing/stopping the activity. That feels like the main reason.

@MartinDotNet, progress... I've added an EDIT 2 section with the results. Appears that I have no event listeners for ActivitySource...

That implies that the services aren't running. You've set it up right, so my guess is some blazor funniness about appdomains I'm afraid. Blazor is very funky about threads and instantiation due to WASM and where things are running. Ultimately it should be running a HostedService
